# How to create a standalone PHP to reindex the store via browser?

Tags: magento2, php, reindex

I have a test environment locked via auth and I would like to create some standalone scripts in PHP in my pub folder in order to optimize the project managers' work, the first file requested is a file to be able to reindex the store indexes completely.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create this file below in your **pub** folder, then access it via the browser.

```php
<?php
header('Content-Encoding: none;');

set_time_limit(0);

$handle = popen("php /var/www/html/bin/magento indexer:reindex", "r");

if (ob_get_level() == 0)
    ob_start();

while(!feof($handle)) {

    $buffer = fgets($handle);
    $buffer = trim(htmlspecialchars($buffer));

    echo $buffer . "<br />";
    echo str_pad('', 4096);

    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}

pclose($handle);
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: we can also restrict this file access for particular Ip only for security.